# Gradle: Extend Task with option flag

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to wrap the call ":myproject:assemble -a" into a task?

I want to provide a one click solution for assembling a single project in a multi project environment. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can simpy create a custom task and set it's `dependsOn` property as follows:

```
assembleMyProject(dependsOn: ':myproject:assemble') {

}
```

Comment: Kind of works but I especially want that "-a" flag to be included. Is that possible?

Comment: @Joschi sorry, didn't mention this.. As for command line args overriding, don't think it's possible. I would rather create standalone bash-script or bat-file to run gradle with exact task and command line arguments

Comment: Right, that could be a solution. I though it might be possible with creating a task. Anyway thank you for your help!